# iOS Invisible Spacer View?

Tags: android, ios

I am struggling to get a simple layout to line up with AutoLayout, constraints, pins, etc.

My layout essentially has a bunch of rows made of 2 UILabels each - for example:

```
Username:    Joe User
Age:         24
City:        New York
```

All of the fields are UILabel and I want to get them to be centered on the view regardless of whether portrait or landscape - the dang IB is fighting me the whole way and posts I have read talk about using "invisible spacer views" to force the alignment I want. I want things aligned exactly as shown above except I want it horizontally center aligned for the orientation with white space on each side (left of field label and right of field data).

I have googled these terms and no one explicitly says "hey dufus here is how to create the spacer views" and that is what I need. Even Apple's docs speak to spacer views but don't tell you how to make them.

I am porting a simple Android app to iOS and this is just killing my time. All this UI setup takes about 2 minutes to setup in Android but seems very painful in iOS.

Help is mightily appreciated.

Below are images showing the android app look I am trying to achieve in portrait (http://jacksonvillekayakfishingclassic.com/portrait.jpg) and landscape (http://jacksonvillekayakfishingclassic.com/landscape.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you want centered? If the lines are different lengths, then centering each line will leave an uneven left edge, not the look you show in the links.

Comment: I want the look I achieved in the Android images. Can you tell me how to create the "transparent spacer views"?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. For what I wanted to do springs and struts and embedding the pieces I wanted centered in subviews was a ton easier than using autolayout at all. This reference helped me immensely https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PgeNPRBrB18&feature=youtu.be